# How do I isolate X in X = ((c + d(e / a)) - (eX)) / ab;

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a real life situation where I must find an average speed (more information below) but I am not good enough at algebra to isolate my variable. Could you please tell me how it's done?

I'm having some variables that I know :

***a : Number of hours available per week = 960 hours***

***b : Target production time = 3.5 weeks***

***c : Current order book value = $700.000***

***d : Projected orders per week = $125.000 / week***

***e : Hours left to reach target production time = 9800 hours***

And those I don't know :

***X = Target rate of delivery ($/h)***

***Y = Target order book value***

So then I made these two equations :

***eq1 : X = Y / ab***

***eq2 : Y = (c + d(e / a)) - (eX)***

If I eliminate Y i get :

***eq : X = ((c + d(e / a)) - (eX)) / ab***

But then I don't know where to start if I want to isolate X. I know very well that the value of X depends on it's own value because the higher the value of X, the higher the value of Y, which will decrease the value of X. I don't know any way to find where this leads.

How should I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it you want to solve the following equation:
$$X = \frac{c + d\frac{e}{a} - eX}{ab}$$
First separate the fraction to obtain
$$X = \frac{c + d\frac{e}{a}}{ab}-\frac{eX}{ab}$$
Then add the right hand term to both sides,
$$X + \frac{eX}{ab}= \frac{c + d\frac{e}{a}}{ab}$$
Now factor out the $X$ in the left hand side,
$$X\left(1+\frac{e}{ab}\right)=\frac{c+d\frac{e}{a}}{ab}.$$
Now divide through by the bracketed factor,
$$X=\frac{\frac{c+d\frac{e}{a}}{ab}}{1+\frac{e}{ab}}.$$
Using algebra of fractions you get the nice form
$$X=\frac{a c+d e}{a^2 b+a e}.$$

Comment: Cool! I should have thought about separating the fraction. It's been a long while. Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to upvote and accept the answer if you found it useful :-)

Comment: Ps make sure the denominator is never zero. Dividing by zero is nonsensical.